# How to create a new column in a Pandas Dataframe based on values in another Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe, with values coming from a second dataframe (picture below). Dataframe 1 contains one column with 9 values, which are just the pattern A,B,C repeated 3 times. How do I get the values from the second dataframe to land on rows corresponding to the letters in the first column? For example, A1, A2 and A3 should land on rows that has letter A. And so on for B and C. Maybe the picture below sheds some light on the situation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
n = {'A':0,'B':0, 'C':0}
def h(rows):
     k = rows["Col 1"]
     n[k] += 1
     return df2[k][n[k]-1]
df1["Col 2"] = df1.apply(h, axis=1)
```